# practical use of lazy initialization on instance variable

Tags: java

I want to understand some practical scenario under which we need to use lazy initialization of instance variable. I have used Singleton pattern for static variables for scenarios where same file handler is available for all the threads but am not really sure on the scenario where it can be used practically.

Regards,
Ramakant

Comment: Don't think of it as "lazy initialization", think of it as "cache".

Comment: any time youre writing a library, for example, and youre not even sure if all of the functions will ever be called.

Comment: All classes and methods are lazy loaded an initialised, in when case you are using it all the time, without knowing it.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a singleton is very resource intensive (memory, processing power, bandwidth, network ports, etc.), you want to create it only on demand, since initializing eagerly wastes the resource in the case where the singleton is never needed.

Another reason: It can make your system more robust if resources to initialize the singleton only exist when the singleton is actually needed.  E.g. suppose the singleton is a print spooler.  If there is no printer currently in the system, it's not worth allocating a spooler that attempts to connect to a non-existent printer.  Since a user should never request to print when there is no printer in the system, the lazy spooler provides exactly the right behavior with no explicit logic.  The user never requests pringing, so the spooler never initializes, and there is never a failed connection attempt.

Other examples of potentially resource-intensive singletons where lazy initialization makes sense:  Loggers, unique SOA services, unique general network services, cache managers, load balancers, pseudo-random number stream generators, resource managers.

Answer (score 0):

For example you have an entity `User` which has an Image associated, so when you read User you don't always need image, so try to load that image lazily when it is actually needed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a template library's template abstraction. The templates are initialised with `String`s, but only compiled into a fast, internal representation when the template is actually requested/run.